# Get height WebViewBridge after loading finish

Tags: react-native, webview

I used https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge to show my html file.
I want add admod below Webview bride so I add webview bride and ads in ScrollView, when webview loaded I will get height of webview and set marginTop to ads = height of webview. But I don't know how to get height of WebviewBridge.
If you have solution or idea please help me.
Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

you can give webView some height(say height/2) as per your interest and render the ads in remaining using scrollView.
Hope this helps

Comment: I want webview show all in scrollview so I need get height of webviewbridge after loaded to change state height of webview. If I set height webview =height/2 webview will scroll in 1/2 screen

Comment: u can use on layout method to get to know the height and assign it accordingly

Comment: Hi, you can use this package to get to know the height of webView  https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview. Hope this helps!

Comment: I used it but if in my webview have img I want add event click to image to zoom it and I can't do it with react-native-autoheight-webview . webview-bridge have function onBridgeMessage to do it so I used webview-bridge

Comment: what i was thinking is , in this also that onbridgeMessage is being used, you can modify onHeightUpdated method in  [common.js](https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview/blob/master/autoHeightWebView/common.js)  and onMessage in  [android.js](https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview/blob/master/autoHeightWebView/index.android.js) to get the desired results